# replacement rules don't account for signs

Tags: replacement

I would like to make a single replacement rule that disregards the sign. I have the following expression:

```
cond = -((-(2 + s^2) (E2 (x1 - x2) + E1 (x2 - x3)) + Sqrt[(2 + s^2)^2 (E2 (x1 - x2) + E1 (x2 - x3))^2 - 32 E1 E2 s^2 (x1 - x2) (x2 - x3)])/((2 + s^2) (E2 (x1 - x2) + E1 (x2 - x3)) + Sqrt[(2 + s^2)^2 (E2 (x1 - x2) + E1 (x2 - x3))^2 - 32 E1 E2 s^2 (x1 - x2) (x2 - x3)]))
```

I would like to simplify this expression, but if I make a replacement rule like

```
cond/.{x2-x1 -> l1}
```

this does nothing because it doesn't realize that `x1-x2 = -l1`. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Why not use `x1 -> x2 - l1`?

Comment: This was an example that showed Mathematica's inability to understand simple replacement rules. If I want to do a more complicated replacement then what you suggest would work, would it?

Comment: The bottom line is that `ReplaceAll` isn't meant to work for math formulas this way. Solve/Eliminate/Reduce etc are. Or you can use `x1 -> x2 - l1` to overcome Replacement limitations. For general approach check the link, have you? hard to say without examples, all problems of the same 'class' should be solvable by a solution that works for one of them.

Comment: "inability to understand simple replacement rules" - more of "replacement rules don't do what you think they do", actually.

Comment: @J.M. what happens if the replacement rule I have is non-linear?

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon you clearly didn't read/check links in the duplicate question. Apart of that, nonlinearity is not a problem, the bottle neck is what `Solve/Eliminate/Reduce` can do.